# Can I include or exclude modules based on variables?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following use case:

- An application is deployed in various versions.
- Across those versions some resources stay the same, some change
- I need to be able to tear down individual versions

Let's see an example configuration:

```
variable "majorVersion" {
  type        = "string"
}

module "media-assets" {
  majorVersion   = "${var.majorVersion}"
  input_bucket   = "uploads-${var.majorVersion}"
  source         = "./modules/media-assets"
}
```

Now assume I want to deploy another version, which adds to it's configuration another module:

```
module "sns" {
  url    = "https://my-api-${var.majorVersion}.xyz.com/sns"
  source = "./modules/sns"
}
```

Since v1 does not require this resource, creating it for v1 would be undesirable. Can I still run this script for majorVersion=v1 after adding the latter part without terraform creating sns resources? Is there a way I can control based on a variable which modules are included and which are not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if version 12 di something better but you can still use the old way of creating resource depending on variable like this:

```
module "sns" {
  count  = ${var.create}
  url    = "https://my-api-${var.majorVersion}.xyz.com/sns"
  source = "./modules/sns"
}
```

If create is equal to 0 the resource won't be created.